# ROS2_control general procedure

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

So I have a KUKA IIWA LBR7 which I want to control via the https://github.com/KCL-BMEIS/lbr_fri_ros2_stack/tree/foxy.
But I am pretty confused by ros2_control framework overall. Although I had a look at the demos I am not sure how to proceed or understand the general procedure:

So I need to launch the controller_manager but how do I connect it to the hardware interfaces??
In ros(1)_control I was able to define it during the construction of he controller_manager via reference

Cheers Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401186/ros2_control-general-procedure/) by [MaxDio](https://answers.ros.org/users/105799/maxdio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-24**:
Should you not ask the [KCL-BMEIS/lbr_fri_ros2_stack](https://github.com/KCL-BMEIS/lbr_fri_ros2_stack) developers/maintainers for guidance?

The chances someone here has experience with the exact package you link are rather low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ros2_control, the hardware interfaces are done through a hardware abstraction layer in the form of a plugin which is loaded dynamically by the resource manager at runtime. This hardware abstraction layer is defined in a separate cpp file, which is then linked to the urdf with the ros2_control xacro tag. In the standard setup, when your launch file is executed, the urdf location is passed to the ros2_control node, which loads the plugin and sets up the hardware interface.

Relevant tutorial links:
[Resource Manager](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#resource-manager) , [Hardware Description in URDF](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#hardware-description-in-urdf) , [Building Interface Class](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/differences_to_ros1/differences_to_ros1.html#migration-guide-to-ros2-control)

Demo links: [Sample hardware abstraction](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_hardware/src/rrbot_system_position_only.cpp) , [with associated ros2_control.urdf file](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_description/rrbot_description/ros2_control/rrbot_system_position_only.ros2_control.xacro) (this is just tacked on at the end of the full urdf [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_description/rrbot_description/urdf/rrbot_system_position_only.urdf.xacro) by importing with xacro), and then [associated high level launch file](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_bringup/launch/rrbot_system_position_only.launch.py).

---

Originally posted by [saltus](https://answers.ros.org/users/37231/saltus/) with karma: 131 on 2022-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `ros2_control` you add it to the config file. If you look at [this config file](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_bringup/config/rrbot_controllers.yaml), you can see that the `forward_position_controller` and `position_trajectory_controller` are parameters for the `controller_manager`. Then you simply need to add the `type` of the controller.

As for how the `controller_manager` knows what to control. I'm pretty sure that's done by [this function](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/2fae87b04057ebd5e84d17138911f34dab4e62e5/ros2_control_demo_hardware/src/rrbot_system_position_only.cpp#L117) and the one below.

The first one returns the states, the second one the commands. I'm pretty sure that the `controller_manager` calls them.

Finally you need to add [something like this](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_description/rrbot_description/ros2_control/rrbot.ros2_control.xacro) to your URDF.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1